# How many states needed for this FSM, and how do I define them?

Tags: automata

I want to define states for FSM that gives an output $1$ if and only if $X$ is dividable by $5$ with a residue of 3. where $X$ is the binary number that the machine got until now (Not Including current digit), for Example:
[image]

Comment: **Hint:** Have one state for each residue modulo 5 the number seen so far can have. One of them accepts.

Comment: so it means maximum there could be 5 states?

Comment: There is no maximum number of states. There is however a minimum number of states (which in this case is $5$ since $3$ and $5$ are coprime).